# Storing database credentials with no server admin controls

Tags: php, mysql, security

I am deploying a dynamic website onto the hosting platform iPage. I am using a db connection with PHP but I can't find a secure way to store the credentials.

iPage has forced me into the following critera:

- Entire website is public, I haven't been able to move the web root to exclude a private directory.
- I have no control over the server's httpd.conf file

They recommend storing the credentials in plain text in the PHP code itself. [No joke](http://members.ipage.com/knowledgebase/read_article.bml?kbid=7499)

The only solution I can think of is setting up a publicly visible directory, setting up .htaccess on it and encrypting the contents of the file, but I'm hoping there is a less "sketchy" solution.

Comment: _"I'm hoping there is a less "sketchy" solution."_ Yeah, find a different hosting provider.

Comment: Note, even if you encrypt the contents of the file that contains the password, you still don't have anywhere secure to store the encryption key.

Comment: Run screaming from this provider. Do not look back. It's 2019 and there's an embarrassment of free or very low cost hosting options. You don't need to be stuck with a platform like that.

Comment: _They recommend storing the credentials in plain text in the PHP code itself_ What the _HECK_? Can you at least change the permissions for viewing a file? Perhaps you could put it in some sort of config file, and change the permissions so only the server itself can view this file.

Comment: To expand a bit on @tadman's comment, note that you can get a full-root unmanaged VPS for the same price as one of their restricted shared packages. Nobody should be using shared hosting nowadays.

Comment: Many VPS/Cloud providers have special packages for start-ups or students where they will give away small plans for free or very nearly free Shop around and you'll find dozens of companies far, far better than iPage which seems firmly stuck in the past.

Comment: Yeah i am not happy about this either, but I am doing the dev work for a tiny start up and they went with iPage because of the low price. Not sure I'll be able to convince them to upgrade.

Comment: See https://lowendbox.com/ -- they continually post hosting specials from various hosts around the world.

Comment: Also note, shared hosting providers are usually woefully behind the curve when it comes to keeping their platform up-to-date. I'll wager they're running a end-of-life PHP version -- which means you'll be *starting* a new project with dead software.

Comment: Either you convince them to upgrade before they get hacked, or you convince them to upgrade after they get hacked and their database leaks out. Your call!